# Storage and Lookup of Voxel Chunks

Tags: java, memory-efficiency

How can one store chunks in such a way that they can be looked up using their XYZ location without wasting memory?

The problem with a `HashMap<Vector3i, Chunk>` is that you have to keep creating `Vector3i` objects, just to use them in the lookup.

I am basically looking for a solution that does not involve the creation of an object to perform a lookup.

Comment: Why do you want O(log(N)) lookup when you have O(1) lookup in the form of an *array*

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden I'd like to be able to retrieve a chunk using its XYZ coordinates

Comment: Math is your friend, index=x+(chunksize*(y+chunksize*z))

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden, ah, thing is that as the player moves around, chunks are loaded and unloaded (and there's a dynamic number of chunks loaded at any one time), so the XYZs would have to be relative etc

Comment: Nope, xyz would only be relative to the chunk origin, not the world origin.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden I am a bit confused as to what you mean. Is the "Chunk origin" the chunk that the player is in?

Comment: Why are you storing each chunk anyway? Wouldn't it be more efficient to save only chunks that have been modified? The rest should be load with noise applied.

Comment: @Savlon, I store any _loaded_ chunks in the memory. Any modified chunks are written to the disk when they're _unloaded_.

Comment: Assuming you have an infinite world you pretty much have to use a map or similar. But if you do most operation on a per chunk basis you won't be doing very many chunk lookups but lots of block lookups within a chunk (quick array lookups). Plus the most common chunk lookup is "what my neighbour" for that reason I allow each chunk to cache it's neighbour in each direction